# I need a YouTube API key for a Company/Business Channel Under my Account

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am running into errors with my YouTube API key I need for the EmbedPlus youtube plugin. I need the key to embed a playlist as a gallery.

I believe the problem is coming from the fact that the playlist/channel I am trying to work with is a "Company page/channel" on YouTube that I am the owner of, but the API key was created under my personal login.

How can I get the API key for a company profile/channel on YouTube?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about software development.

Comment: The API key just allows access to the API and there isn't separate ones for playlists/profiles/channels. Most likely the issue is with the plugin. You could try stating what the actual error is.

Comment: May be, you are using on a server and did not make any server key. @johnh10 is right, you have problem in creating key. Please be sure, if not comment, your problem, with a little bit explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a developer and I don't understand if I haven't used the right language. I am getting a "Sorry, there was a YouTube API error: Received HTTP code 301 from proxy after CONNECT" telling me that I have improperly created my API key. I followed the instructions from the plugin to the letter, to create the server key. So the only thing I could think is that since my personal google/youtube account does not have any videos or a channel or anything, the API key needs to be created under the youtube account/channel that has all of the company's videos.

Comment: I was directed to this forum to get support for the youtube API key, that is why I posted here.

Comment: @LauraL can you please elaborate your steps on making api key, I think there is an error. edit your question a little bit. steps by steps Thanks

Comment: I checked the YouTube EmbedPlus code, and the although the error message says it's a YouTube API error, it's actually a WP error (they use the same code for both). That message does not imply you have improperly created the API key. It sounds more like your server is using a proxy that limits external connections.

Comment: @Kumar Sure. I went to Google Developers, created a new project, enabled the YouTube Data API v3, then I created the Credentials choosing "Server key" and received the API key to use in the WordPress plugin.

Comment: @johnh10 Thank you. I had previously contacted my hosting service about the issue and they looked into it and said the error was the YouTube API error. I have another call out to them asking about limits to external connections.

Comment: @john10, thanks to your help, I was able to point our webhosting service to the real issue and it was resolved. THANK YOU.